# Почему не компилируется данный С++ код?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть такой код на С++ (упрощённо).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Component
{
};

template <typename T> class Storage
{
    public:
        template <typename U> U* get()
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
};

template <typename T> class Test
{
    public:
        void test()
        {
            Storage<T>().get<Component>();
        }
};

int main()
{
    Test<Component>().test();

    return 0;
}
```

И происходит ошибка сборки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если явно указать в методе test() используемый тип, то всё прекрасно собирается

```
template <typename T> class Test
{
    public:
        void test()
        {
            Storage<Component>().get<Component>();
        }
};
```

Не могу понять, в чем причина. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут необходимо указать, что зависимое (от параметров шаблона) имя `get` является именем шаблона
`Storage<T>().template get<Component>();`

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь.